# Why sometimes acronyms are pronounced as a word and sometimes they are not?

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms, initialisms

Why is NASA (the National Aeronautics and Space Administration) pronounced as "na·suh" but USA (the United States of America) not pronounced as "u·suh"?

Comment: Related: [What determines how one should vocalise an abbreviation when reading aloud?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552490/).